# ruby test unit gem doesn't show dots for passed test

Tags: ruby, testunit

Ruby test unit gem doesn't show dots for passed test. I'm running on Ubuntu 11.04 .

It shows 'E' and 'F' for failure, but nothing for pass. This problem dissapears if I comment `gem 'test-unit'`  line, but in that case test-unit 2.x features (like omit, pend) is not available.

Comment: Have you checked whether there's a command line option for showing/hiding dots?

Comment: What is the exact command you use to run our tests? Test unit does have different verbose levels that you can specify from the command line.

Comment: Also, the version of Ruby you are running

Comment: Please post the output of: `ruby --version` and `gem env`.

Comment: Can you paste your test-unit.yml? More info on configuration here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/test-unit/2.4.0/Test/Unit

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use 'turn' gem for more pretty output for the testing.

Just install the `gem turn` and use it in your app.

Comment: `turn` isn't compatible with `Test::Unit 2` https://github.com/guard/guard-test/issues/8#issuecomment-2242319

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ruby 1.9 did you try MiniTest? It's include in Ruby and the output is well formatted,

> 83 tests, 106 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 1 skips

You can learn more about MiniTest [here](http://www.bootspring.com/2010/09/22/minitest-rubys-test-framework/)